# "CONTAINS" not working in View Criteria

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created a View Criteria in ADF that searches employees on the basis of employee name and name is passed through a bind variable. When I search using equals it fetches the result.

[image: using EQUALS here]

However, my requirement is to search using CONTAINS. When I use CONTAINS it doesn't fetch out any data and shows no record found.

[image: Using CONTAINS]

Comment: Your database is MySQL but you've tagged the question Oracle 12c. Which is correct? Do you have a minimal example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Sorry i am using jdeveloper 12c and database is MySQL and minimal example all i have are those pic only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was occurring because i was querying  MySql but syntax which was gong through here was of ORACLE , so what we can do here is change the query execution mode from **database** to **in memory** this will resolve the error and will work fine and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that contains uses Oracle style wild cards which might not be the same as what MySQL expects. 
Turn on fine logging on the ADF BC layer to see the SQL that is issued and verify.